# What do smartphone manufacturers do differently with their cameras than the Raspberry Pi module camera

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, smartphones

There is a huge difference in quality between the image/video taken by the latest iPhone or Samsung smartphone compared to that taken by the Raspberry Pi camera module. What is different about the smartphone hardware or software that enables such superior image/video quality when compared to the Raspberry Pi camera module?

Comment: What is the relative computational power of an iPhone vs. a Raspberry Pi? The image quality of current smartphones is based, to a large degree on the computational processing they do, not the quality of the hardware collecting the image data.

Comment: So the smartphone's camera image sensor is of identical grade with that of a Raspberry Pi camera, but they manage to bring up all the image quality and crispness through software image processing? That seems unbelievable.

Comment: The optical part is different.

Comment: @pkout That's not what the comment above says. But a lot of (as opposed to *all* of) the difference can be attributed to computational photography: e.g. taking multiple frames and computationally merging them to reduce the influence of noise, etc. If the raw data from the iPhone sensor were processed the same way the raw data from the Pi is, the results would be much less impressive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say the difference is 20% due to hardware and 80% due to software.

## The hardware side

- The smartphone probably has better optics and wider aperture;
- The smartphone has focusing. The Pi has fixed focus (so it's only good for objects more than 1m away, see [hyperfocal distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperfocal_distance)). But that means that most objects, especially the close ones, are somewhat blurrier than what they would be if there were proper focusing;
- The smartphone has a bigger sensor, meaning better signal-to-noise ratio.

## The software side

This is the big one. Just look at [any video explaning RAW processing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MbtlSfzGcg4). Keep in mind that the one you see on the left ("before") is not even 100% unprocessed - it already has demosaicing and toning curve and some close to correct white balance. What the sensor actually "sees" is even more unconvincing.

This post-processing is a lot of work, and the smartphone does all that mostly automatically, using a combination of fixed algorithms, some environment detection (e.g. - detect faces in the image - use skin smoothing filters), and probably neural networks these days. And the firmware is frequently updated, so it is state of the art.

Digital photography is a complicated thing, and it's enough if your software is even a little wrong about some parameter to turn you image quality into crap. E.g. slightly inaccurate white balance is enough to make the picture thoroughly unconvincing.

## The other stuff

How are you comparing the two? Is it on the same display? Because I used to own an iPhone, whose photos looked gorgeous on its screen, but weren't at all that impressive when transferred to a PC and viewed on its otherwise pretty good monitor. Smartphone manufacturers try hard to make their camera + display combo work well, so they are well tuned to each other.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone X has a 12 Megapixel camera and the Raspberry Pi Camera that I found has an 8 Megapixel sensor. That alone would cause a significant difference.

Combined with all the research and development that phone manufactures put into choosing the right aperture, adding HDR and Image Stabilization alongside the massive amounts of work put into software to make the images much better than they would be accounts for the difference in quality.

Comment: Actually camera with 8Mpix resolution can give much better photos than camera with 12Mpix resolution. The quality is limited by another factors, like physical size and quality of the sensor, and optics. Difference between 12Mpix and 8Mpix doesn't mean a thing...